# Cart Price Rules: More than two discount at the same time

Tags: price, rules

I have a requirement to apply two discount at the same time on my shopping cart value.. there is any way to do this currently only one shopping cart rule is applied at a time.

please give me a solution for that...thank you.

Comment: Stop further rules processing is that set to No?

Comment: i already tried it..but it is not working.   I want two discount at the same time...for example in first line 50$ discount & in next line 40$ so total discount will be 90$  in grand total... i want to  show them in separate lines with different names.

Answer (score 0):

Magento will only process one discount at a time, to acomplish this you will need to rewrite the core.  This is to stop allowing people to add discounts over and over again.